# Further / recursive object destructuring

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this:

```
const {ops} = getOplogStreamInterpreter(strm);

ops.del.subscribe(v => {
  console.log('delete happened 1.');
});

ops.insert.subscribe(v => {
  console.log('insert happened 1.');
});

ops.update.subscribe(v => {
  console.log('update happened 1.');
});
```

just wondering if it's somehow possible to do this:

```
const {{insert,del,update}} = getOplogStreamInterpreter(strm);
```

basically further destructure the returned object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
const { ops: { del, insert, update } } = getOplogStreamInterpreter(strm);

del.subscribe(v => {
  console.log('delete happened 1.');
});

insert.subscribe(v => {
  console.log('insert happened 1.');
});

update.subscribe(v => {
  console.log('update happened 1.');
});
```